# Qt - Create a simple theming system (changing colors of GUI)

Tags: c++, qt, themes, qtstylesheets

I want to be able to create an simple internal theming system for my program (by internal I mean I don't need to be able to load custom themes from user system... all themes will be embedded inside the program itself.)
I can think of some ways:

- simply put all color inside the main stylesheet of the program, every time the colors need to change, retrieve main stylesheet, parse and change the colors, and then reapply it again (or have multiple stylesheet with different colors, and apply them when its needed).
- Create a top widget that only hold the colors for each widget, and then a child widget that hold other stylesheet for other styling, and all the UI as child of this widget... in this way we need to only change the first stylesheet.
- ... (not sure about other ways, but I'm sure there is some... maybe using QStyle or something..?)

I'm not sure what is the best way to achieve what I'm after, that will be best at both performance and the code itself...
I know the first way will be heavy in performance side, to each time change the whole stylesheet and rerender the whole program. (I think at least)
the second option though, I'm not sure how it will work, I mean its any better then the first one?!
or there is any other better methods..?

Comment: Have you considered `QProxyStyle`?

Comment: @Genjutsu if I use that I will still be able to use the custom stylesheet that I created..? manually paint them will be a pain..? and tbh never used it before, so not sure how it can be used here.

Answer (score 1):

you should create a `.qss` file and add it in your `.qrc` like you add your icons.
then write all your stylesheet there. you can have multiple `Style.qss` files and these files are your themes and whenever you change it your theme will change.

1. add your `Style.qss` File in your Resources(.qrc)
2. write these codes in `main.cpp`

**Load the application style**

```
QFile  styleFile(":/style.qss");
styleFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
```

**Apply the loaded stylesheet**

```
QString  style(styleFile.readAll());
a.setStyleSheet(style);
```

For more information :

https://github.com/GTRONICK/QSS

https://github.com/ColinDuquesnoy/QDarkStyleSheet

Comment: thank you, but the thing is I believe reapplying a big stylesheet can be some time heavy in performance side... (as I said in the question)

Comment: I use this way many times and I didn't have a performance issues, If you look at apps like [QGIS](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/resources/themes/Blend%20of%20Gray), they use `.qss` to set their theme.

Comment: Ok thank you, but does it better to just keep the coloring at top widget, and put other stylesheet as child of it..? so the color will apply one them and for changing them we only need to change first one, its should be better...

Comment: Please do not speculate and try this very simple solution first and ONLY IF you experience slowdowns due to applying large QSS to every widget, then try to invent some optimizations and try if you can make it faster yoursel (which I doubt). Remember the rule number one: premature optimization is the root of all eveil.